# How to return a dataset for next 30 days group by each day

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar, date-arithmetic

i have a query like this returns today salary of the employee

```
select salary
from   employee_salary
where  sysdate between start_date and end_date.
```

i want to generate a query which returns salary(salary display based on each day - Salary comes to the column from number of hours working) of employees  group by each day for next 30 days .The real question is how to increment

```
sysdate+1 between start_date and end_date
sysdate+2 between start_date and end_date
```

on same query. so it generate sum of salary each day work.
 So dataset will be like

```
date       name salary
sysdate+1  emp1 100
sysdate+1  emp2 90
sysdate+2  emp1 30
...................
sysdate+30 emp1 130
```

please note sysdate+x actually returns a date. How can i modify my query to return data like this for next sysdate+30 days .

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output based on that data.

Comment: I think you need to give some more infor about the data in your table and what you expect.

Comment: Employee_salary have columns of name  , salary, start_date and end_date.  so i want to check for each day for each employee is in between that date range or not for each day for 30 next days .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a list of the next thirty days. Join the calendar to the `employee_salary` table, filtering by the date range. Sum the salaries for each day using the aggregate syntax.

So:

```
 with cal as (
    select sysdate+level as dt    
    from dual
    connect by level <= 30
)
select cal.dt as "date"
       , sum(es.salary) as sal_daily_total
from cal
     left outer join employee_salary es
     on es.start_date <= cal.dt
     and es.end_date >= cal.dt
group by cal.dt
```

The obvious snag is that the total will include salary calculated for weekends and public holidays, if the `employee _salary` date range spans them. If that is a problem please **edit your question** to clarify your requirments.

Comment: I don't see anything​ in your revision which invalidate​s my solution. So I suggest you try it and see how it works out.

Comment: After tweaking around and with some changes was able to get it to work. Thank you